# winapi get handles opened to current process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10, handle

Is there any way to get all of the handles that have been opened to the current process on Win10?
I have seen NtQuerySystemInformation but SystemProcessInformation only returns handle count and not the handles themselves.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    BYTE Reserved1[48];
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved2;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    ULONG SessionId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    SIZE_T PeakVirtualSize;
    SIZE_T VirtualSize;
    ULONG Reserved4;
    SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
    PVOID Reserved5;
    SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    PVOID Reserved6;
    SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved7[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

How can I get all of the handles that have been opened to a process, preferable with the access level included as well, and the opener process's name?

Comment: I'm curious about the use-case. Why do you need this list of handles? What are you going to do with them? What is the underlying problem (if any) getting this list would solve?

Comment: HandleCount is probably the number of handles opened **in** your process, not to it.

Comment: you can query `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` - you got list of all opened handles in system. you can detect the handles opened on concrete process of course. and it desired access

Comment: What is the return type of SystemExtendedHandleInformation?

Comment: The use-case would be to see if any denylisted applications have opened a handle to an application.It would be a POC of sort of anti debug/anti access feature.

Comment: you got `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX` structure. look - https://pastebin.com/ig1eVPBa

Comment: Thanks. That looks great. Can you elaborate how did you find info regarding this struct? Historical knowledge?

Comment: look for https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntexapi.h#L2534

Comment: *"It would be a POC of sort of anti debug/anti access feature."* - I doubt an answer to this question will get you there. If you need to control who can open a handle to your process, let the OS deal with that. Processes are securable objects after all. Obviously, this won't work unless you're running in a controlled environment. Which you likely aren't. In that case, however, identifying whether a process should be on your denylist won't work, either.